# PyQt4: QTreeView constructor causes crash: QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Tags: python, crash, pyqt, pyside, qapplication

I run into a strange behavior, where my QApplication seems not initialize correctly.

I have two modules: `foo.py` and `bar.py`.

`bar.py` content:

```
module:  bar
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MyTreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(parent)
```

`foo.py` content:

```
# module: foo
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import bar

class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self._name = name

        self.setMinimumSize(500, 200)

        self.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())

        self._tree = bar.MyTreeView(name)
        self.layout().addWidget(self._tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = MyDialog('foo')
    dialog.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When running `foo.py` I get the following error message:
`QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice`

The debugger stops while calling the QTreeView constructor:

```
super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(parent)
```

What's going wrong here?

---

System: `Windows 7`

Python: `2.7.9`

PyQt: `PyQt4` - `4.8.6`

Comment: Works fine for me. Surely you're not really using pyqt-**4.8.6** (released 2011)?! That's probably your qt version.

Comment: Works fine for me too, running with PySide version 1.2.4

Comment: I suspect the bar.py shown is not what is actually in the file

Comment: as three_pineapples allready said, you probably have some more in your `bar.py`. Move the import of bar.py after the constructor of QApplication and do the class declearation, using the bar import, later as well